# Parameter int howmany in Arduino i2C slave receiver

Tags: arduino

I have the following example code of a Arduino Slave i2C. Taken from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

```c
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(8);                // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  Serial.begin(9600);           // start serial for output
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

// function that executes whenever data is received from master
// this function is registered as an event, see setup()
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (1 < Wire.available()) { // loop through all but the last
    char c = Wire.read(); // receive byte as a character
    Serial.print(c);         // print the character
  }
  int x = Wire.read();    // receive byte as an integer
  Serial.println(x);         // print the integer
}
```

In the method `void receiveEvent(int howMany)`, what exactly is the functionality of the parameter `int howMany`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `receiveEvent` is provided as an event handler to `Wire.onReceive()`.

So, from the documentation of [Wire.onReceive](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireOnReceive)

> handler: the function to be called when the slave receives data; this should take a single int parameter (the number of bytes read from the master) and return nothing, e.g.: `void myHandler(int numBytes)`

It contains the amount of bytes of the received data.